# Find groups with matching rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of people (`CarOwners`) and the types of cars they own

```
+-------+-------+
| Name  | Model |
+-------+-------+
| Bob   | Camry |
| Bob   | Civic |
| Bob   | Prius |
| Kevin | Civic |
| Kevin | Focus |
| Mark  | Civic |
| Lisa  | Focus |
| Lisa  | Civic |
+-------+-------+
```

Given a name, how do i find other people with the **exact** same cars? For example, if i'm targeting Mark, no one else has ONLY a Civic so the query would return nothing. If i'm targeting Lisa, the query would return

```
+-------+-------+
| Name  | Model |
+-------+-------+
| Kevin | Civic |
| Kevin | Focus |
+-------+-------+
```

Because Kevin has the exact same cars as Lisa. If i targeted Kevin, the query would return Lisa.

I created a cte which contains my target persons cars, but i'm not sure how to implement the "exact match" requirement. All of my attempts return results with subset matches.

```
with LisaCars as (
    SELECT Model FROM CarOwners WHERE Name = 'Lisa'
)
SELECT Name, Model
FROM CarOwners
WHERE Model in (SELECT * FROM LisaCars) AND Name != 'Lisa'
```

This query would return all people who have either a Civic or a Focus, which isn't what i'm looking for.

```
+-------+-------+
| Name  | Model |
+-------+-------+
| Bob   | Civic |
| Kevin | Civic |
| Kevin | Focus |
| Mark  | Civic |
+-------+-------+
```

Comment: so you want full matches, not partial? i.e. only if a person has the exact same cars (no more no less) than the person queried?

Comment: Yah. My sample query provides partial matches already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This counts the number of rows for each `name` using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)(cte) with `count()` [**`over()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx).

Then the `matches` cte uses a self-join where the names do not match, the models match, the count of models for each name match, and one of those names is `'Lisa'`. The `having` clause ensures that count of matched rows (`count(*)`) matches the number of models that `name` has.

`matches` itself would only return the `name` of each person, so we join back to the source table `t` to get the full list of models for each match.

```
;with cte as (
  select *
    , cnt = count(*) over (partition by name)
  from t
)
, matches as (
  select x2.name
  from cte as x 
    inner join cte as x2
       on x.name <> x2.name
      and x.model = x2.model
      and x.cnt   = x2.cnt 
      and x.name  = 'Lisa'
  group by x2.name, x.cnt
  having count(*) = x.cnt
)
select t.* 
from t
  inner join matches m
    on t.name = m.name
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/SUKP78304

returns:

```
+-------+-------+
| name  | model |
+-------+-------+
| Kevin | Civic |
| Kevin | Focus |
+-------+-------+
```

---

We could also write it without the ctes, but it makes it a little harder to follow:

```
select t.*
from t 
  inner join (
    select x2.Name
    from (
      select *, cnt = count(*) over (partition by name) 
      from t 
      where name='Lisa'
      ) as x
      inner join (
      select *, cnt = count(*) over (partition by name) 
      from t
      ) as x2
        on x.name <> x2.name
       and x.model = x2.model
       and x.cnt   = x2.cnt 
    group by x2.name, x.cnt
    having count(*) = x.cnt
  ) as m 
    on t.name = m.name
```

Comment: Is there anyway to change `and x.name  = 'Lisa'` to a list of names, and then receive a result set that is partitioned by exact same car ownership? Right now, i am calling this query with a loop in Java, passing each name. It feels extremely inefficient.

Comment: Hi Zim, i posted the new question here with my desired result, hoping you can continue to save my day! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42821465/how-to-execute-statement-for-each-row-and-return-entire-result. I will also check out your link.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is comparing the ordered concatenated model value for each name.

```
with cte as (
select name,model,
     STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + t2.model
          FROM t t2
          WHERE t1.name=t2.name
          ORDER BY model
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') concat_value
from t t1 
) 
select distinct x2.name,x2.model
from cte x1
join cte x2 on x1.concat_value=x2.concat_value and x1.name<>x2.name
where x1.name='Kevin'
```

If your version of SQL Server supports [`STRING_AGG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt790580.aspx), the query can be simplified as

```
with cte as (
    select name,model,
         STRING_AGG(model,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY model) as concat_value
    from t t1 
    ) 
select distinct x2.name,x2.model
from cte x1
join cte x2 on x1.concat_value=x2.concat_value and x1.name<>x2.name
where x1.name='Kevin'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it's

```
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#temp') is not null
drop table #temp

create table #temp (name varchar(100),model varchar(100))

insert into #temp values('Bob','Camry')
insert into #temp values('Bob','Civic')
insert into #temp values('Bob','Prius')
insert into #temp values('Kevin','Focus')
insert into #temp values('Kevin','Civic')
insert into #temp values('Mark','Civic')
insert into #temp values('Lisa','Focus')
insert into #temp values('Lisa','Civic')

select * from (
select row_number() over(partition by name order by (select null)) as n,
row_number() over(partition by model order by (select null)) as m,*
from #temp) as a
where  n = m
order by name
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want your match to be **exact**, we should add the number of cars each person owns as an additional field. Assuming your table name is '#owners' The following query

```
select  *
        , (select COUNT(*)
            from #owners o2
            where o2.name = o1.name) as num
    from #owners o1
```

gives us the table

```
+-------+-------+-----+
| Name  | Model | num |
+-------+-------+-----+
| Bob   | Camry | 3   |
| Bob   | Civic | 3   |
| Bob   | Prius | 3   | 
| Kevin | Civic | 2   |
| Kevin | Focus | 2   |
| Mark  | Civic | 1   |
| Lisa  | Focus | 2   |
| Lisa  | Civic | 2   |
+-------+-------+-----+
```

Then we want to join this table to itself matching model and count. We use a CTE so that it reads better. The following query

```
; with
    OwnedCount as (
        select  *
                , (select COUNT(*)
                    from #owners o2
                    where o2.name = o1.name) as num
            from #owners o1
    )
select *
    from OwnedCount o1
    inner join OwnedCount o2
        on o1.model = o2.model 
        and o1.num = o2.num
```

gives us this table

```
+-------+-------+-----+-------+-------+-----+
| Name  | Model | num | Name  | Model | num |
+-------+-------+-----+-------+-------+-----+
| Bob   | Camry | 3   | Bob   | Camry | 3   |
| Bob   | Civic | 3   | Bob   | Civic | 3   |
| Bob   | Prius | 3   | Bob   | Prius | 3   |
| Kevin | Civic | 2   | Kevin | Civic | 2   |
| Kevin | Civic | 2   | Lisa  | Civic | 2   |
| Kevin | Focus | 2   | Kevin | Focus | 2   |
| Kevin | Focus | 2   | Lisa  | Focus | 2   |
| Mark  | Civic | 1   | Mark  | Civic | 1   |
| Lisa  | Civic | 2   | Kevin | Civic | 2   |
| Lisa  | Civic | 2   | Lisa  | Civic | 2   |
| Lisa  | Focus | 2   | Kevin | Focus | 2   |
| Lisa  | Focus | 2   | Lisa  | Focus | 2   |
+-------+-------+-----+-------+-------+-----+
```

Lastly, you filter the results by the name you want

```
declare @given_name varchar(32) = 'Lisa'
; with
    OwnedCount as (
        select  *
                , (select COUNT(*)
                    from #owners o2
                    where o2.name = o1.name) as num
            from #owners o1
    )
select o2.name, o2.model
    from OwnedCount o1
    inner join OwnedCount o2
        on o1.model = o2.model 
        and o1.num = o2.num
    where o1.name = @given_name
        and o2.name <> @given_name
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,i think it is much easier and short code with just one partition function.

```
    declare @t table(Name varchar(50),Model varchar(50))
    insert into @t values
    ('Bob','Camry')
    ,('Bob','Civic')
    ,('Bob','Prius')
    ,('Kevin','Civic')
    ,('Kevin','Focus')
    ,('Mark','Civic')
    ,('Lisa','Focus')
    ,('Lisa','Civic')

    declare @input varchar(50)='Lisa'

    ;with 
CTE1 AS
(
select name,model,ROW_NUMBER()over( order by name) rn
 from @t
where name=@input
)
,cte2 as
(
select t.name,t.Model
,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by t.name order by t.name) rn3
from @t t 
inner JOIN
cte1    c on t.Model=c.model 
where   t.Name !=@input
)
select * from cte2 c
where exists(select rn3 from cte2 c1 
where c1.name=c.name and c1.rn3=(select max(rn) from cte1)
)
```