# How to select records with same foreign list (two tables)?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select, collections

I have two tables:

Persons:

```
PersonId   Name
--------------------
1          Peter
2          Steven
3          Luck
```

Hobbies:

```
PersonId   Hobbie
--------------------
1          Running
1          Cooking
2          Running
3          Running
3          Cooking
```

I need to select only persons who have the **same hobbies** and the same **amount** of hobbies

Example Result:

```
PersonId
--------------
1
3
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? mysql <> sql server.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42700771/find-groups-with-matching-rows/42703943#42703943 for the same question

Answer (score 0):

```
with hobbies (PersonId, Hobbie) as
(select 1, 'Running' from dual union all
select 1, 'Cooking'  from dual union all
select 2, 'Running' from dual union all
select 3, 'Running'  from dual union all
select 3, 'Cooking'  from dual ),

src as (
    select PersonId,Hobbie,count(Hobbie) over (partition by PersonId) as cnt from hobbies group by PersonId,Hobbie
       )
select distinct s1.PersonId from src s1 join src s2 
on s1.hobbie=s2.hobbie 
and s1.cnt=s2.cnt
and s1.PersonId<>s2.PersonId
```

You can try this approach, by taking the count first and then joining the count and hobbies

Comment: Where does the `id` column in your CTE come from?

Comment: The count at (PersonId, hobbie) level will be 1 for each row

Comment: @JohnBollinger - It was a typo. I have corrected it

Comment: With the edit, @StefanoZanini's observation now applies.  `PersonId` is among the CTE's grouping columns, so now every row of the CTE will have a `cnt` of 1.

Comment: I have added a `partition by` to overcome the bug. Please review

Comment: Changing to a window function should produce the desired counts (on a DBMS that supports them, with includes SQL Server but not MySQL).  The overall query still does not appear to produce the correct result, however: it will select individual members of pairs who have the same number of hobbies and *at least one* in common, whereas the OP wants both members of each pair who have *all* hobbies in common.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using MySql, you can achieve that with this approach.

First of all, you aggregate all the rows of the same person, counting the hobbies and concatenating them

```
select  p.PersonId,
        count(h.Hobbie) cnt,
        GROUP_CONCAT(h.Hobbie SEPARATOR ',') hobbies
from    person p
join    (select * from hobbies order by Hobbie) h
on      p.PersonId = h.PersonId
group by p.PersonId;
```

Note that to ensure that the concatenation is the same, you have to select the hobbies from a previously ordered vesion of `hobbies` table, otherwise different ordering may yeld to different values of the concatenation.

Then you can use the result of this query as a table that you join with itself, using as a join criteria both the count and the concatenation of the hobbies, but excluding the rows with the same `PersonId`.

```
select  t1.PersonId, t2.PersonId
from    (
        select  p.PersonId,
                count(h.Hobbie) cnt,
                GROUP_CONCAT(h.Hobbie SEPARATOR ',') hobbies
        from    person p
        join    (select * from hobbies order by Hobbie) h
        on      p.PersonId = h.PersonId
        group by p.PersonId
        ) t1
join    (
        select  p.PersonId,
                count(h.Hobbie) cnt,
                GROUP_CONCAT(h.Hobbie SEPARATOR ',') hobbies
        from    person p
        join    (select * from hobbies order by Hobbie) h
        on      p.PersonId = h.PersonId
        group by p.PersonId
        ) t2
on      t1.cnt = t2.cnt and
        t1.hobbies = t2.hobbies and
        t1.PersonId <> t2.PersonId
```

**You can see it in action [here](http://rextester.com/WAQEZO40032)**

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using a `HAVING` clause with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT h1.PersonId AS p1, h2.PersonId AS p2
FROM Hobbies AS h1
INNER JOIN Hobbies AS h2 
   ON h1.Hobbie = h2.Hobbie AND h1.PersonId <> h2.PersonId
GROUP BY p1, p2                           
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                  FROM Hobbies
                  WHERE PersonId = h1.PersonId)
       AND                    
       COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                  FROM Hobbies
                  WHERE PersonId = h2.PersonId)
```

The query picks all pairs of persons having in common a number of hobbies that is equal to the number of hobbies of each of the individual persons of the pair.

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/ZLLEW63195)

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you are using a DBMS that supports common table expressions (CTEs), such as SQL Server but *not* MySQL, you could do it like this:

```
with (
  select PersonId as pid, count(*) as c
  from hobbie
  group by PersonId
) as hobbie_count
with (
  select h1.PersonId as pid1, h2.PersonId as pid2, count(*) as c
  from hobbie h1
    join hobbie h2
      on h1.hobbie = h2.hobbie
  group by h1.PersonId, h2.PersonId
  having h1.PersonId <> h2.PersonId
) as cohob_count
select cc.pid1, cc.pid2
from hobbie_count hc1
  join cohob_count cc
    on hc1.pid = cc.pid1 and hc1.c = cc.c
  join hobbie_count hc2
    on cc.pid2 = hc2.pid and cc.c = hc2.c
```

The `hobbie_count` CTE counts how many hobbies each person has, and the `cohob_count` CTE counts how many hobbies each pair has in common.  The final query joins those (the first one twice) to select the pairs for which the number of hobbies in common is equal to each person's total number of hobbies.

You can still take this general approach if you happen to be using a DBMS that does not support CTEs (e.g. MySQL).  In that case, you could convert the CTEs to full-blown ordinary views or to inline views.